# how do I run code when a node is added to a C# TreeView control

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I need to run code when a new node is added to a treeview control. Control_Added event that comes with the control does not get fired when a new node is added to the TreeView which is weird as I expected that it was a control, a node I mean. What event should be used for this?

Thanks..

Comment: Please modify your tags, telling us what UI Framework(WinForms, WPF etc.) you are using, this also helps you with a wider spread of people who might be able to help you.

Comment: how do you add the nodes to the Treeview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event for that.  This is not unusual, events are meant to tell your code that something of interest happened, something you don't otherwise know about.  The user of your program cannot add a node to the treeview, only your code can do that.  You already know about it.

Inheriting a class from TreeView and adding the event you want, as well as a public helper method that adds the node and raises the event is the workaround.  It isn't a very good one because there is still a backdoor to add nodes that you cannot easily close.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer which also helps look at events in a new perspective for me.